# Como obtener el ultimo registro de una tabla en SQLite

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

Saludos...quisiera que alguien me ayudara con una duda acerca de obtener el ultimo registro de una tabla por favor. He estado usando el siguiente codigo pero no me esta funcionando correctamente. Cualquier ayuda es muy bienvenida, gracias de antemano.

```
public class StatusFragment extends Fragment {
Handler handler;
double[] values;
ConnectionSQLiteHelper connectorStatus;
TextView voltBattery,currentBattery,tempBattery,powerBattery,impedBattery,healthBattery,averagePower,cycleCount,crankAmpere,memory;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status, container, false);
    connectorStatus = new ConnectionSQLiteHelper(getActivity(),"bd_batmon",null,1);
    voltBattery = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textVoltage);
    currentBattery = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textCurrent);
    tempBattery = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textTemperature);
    powerBattery = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textPower);
    impedBattery = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textImpedance);
    healthBattery = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textHealth);
    averagePower = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textAverage);
    cycleCount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textCycle);
    crankAmpere = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textCrank);
    memory = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textMemory);
    handler = new Handler();
    values = new double[3];
    handler.post(upDate);
    return v;
}

private Runnable upDate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        SQLiteDatabase db_History = connectorStatus.getReadableDatabase();
        String get_History = "SELECT * FROM "+Utilities.TABLE_HISTORY+" WHERE "+Utilities.ID_HISTORY+"=(SELECT MAX("+Utilities.ID_HISTORY+") FROM "+Utilities.TABLE_HISTORY+")";
        Cursor cursor = db_History.rawQuery( get_History, null );
        if(cursor.moveToLast()) {
            values[0] = cursor.getDouble( cursor.getColumnIndex( Utilities.VOLTAGE_BATTERY ) );
            values[1] = cursor.getDouble( cursor.getColumnIndex( Utilities.CURRENT_BATTERY ) );
            values[2] = cursor.getDouble( cursor.getColumnIndex( Utilities.TEMP_BATTERY ) );
            cursor.close();
            db_History.close();
        }
        Toast.makeText( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), values[0] + "-" + values[1] + "-" + values[2], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        /*voltBattery.setText(String.valueOf(values[0]));
        currentBattery.setText(String.valueOf(values[1]));
        tempBattery.setText(String.valueOf(values[2]));
        double power = values[0]*values[1];
        double impedance = values[0]/values[1];
        powerBattery.setText(String.valueOf(power));
        impedBattery.setText(String.valueOf(impedance));*/
        handler.postDelayed(this,3000);
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Puedes intentar hacer un ORDER BY DESC en la query para que el primer resultado en el cuerosr sea el ultimo registro de la tabla

Comment: gracias me funciono, ademas tambien era necesario cambiar el el nombre de la base de datos "bd_batmon" por "db_batmon" en esta linea:                                         
connectorStatus = new ConnectionSQLiteHelper(getActivity(),"bd_batmon",null,1);